Best Way to Include Code Snippets in HTML for a Technical Blog
I'm working on a technical blog that includes code snippets, and I want to make sure they’re easy to read, well-formatted, and accessible. Currently, I’m considering using  and  tags but am not sure how to best combine them for readability and accessibility. Additionally, I’d like to support syntax highlighting and ensure screen readers interpret the code correctly. Are there specific HTML techniques or tools that can help me achieve this?
I’m open to suggestions for CSS styles or any additional HTML tags that would help, as well as best practices for code blocks that fit well with various themes and screen sizes.
